# Can CKAN stream GeoJSON?

Tags: ckan

I have uploaded several spatial datasets to a CKAN repository and would like to stream geoJSON from them. I have used the datastore API like:

datastore_search?resource_id=d6fa3911-ae95-4100-8c4f-78aa388c97c9

...but it only returns the attributes, not the geometry. I know the geometry is available because I have put up a dataset in GeoJSON format and when I select Explore->Preview it shows the features on the map. Is it possible?

Thanks

Jim

Comment: Have you uploaded a GeoJSON file or a CSV (or Excel, etc.) file with GeoJSON in one of the columns? And what version of CKAN is this? If possible give a public link to the resource.

Comment: The link to the resource is: http://covckan.canadacentral.cloudapp.azure.com/dataset/firehalls_package/resource/78791e62-2637-46ad-9a6d-ca57705d82a9/download/firehalls.geojson When I access this link through a Python script it returns the resources as geojson, which is what I want. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something :-) What do you need in addition to that link? Or maybe put another way, what do you specifically mean by "streaming" [as opposed to downloading]?

Comment: Actually I have what I want. In the case of GeoJSON or KML I want our ArcGIS Server software to request these sources from CKAN so that it can render them as layers upon a map. Ideally the output would have a header such as "Content-Type: application/json" or a header for KML so that the browser displays it in a stream as opposed to try to download it, but that is not an issue here because I am not using the browser, rather I am using Arcgis Server, which treats it as a data source and renders it onto the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get what you want by changing the link to this:
https://YOURCKANURL/dataset/DATASET_ID/resource/RESOURCE_ID/download/ANYTHING_YOU_WANT.geojson

The datastore stores tabular data and not GeoJSON data, so trying to get a GeoJSON file resource uploaded to CKAN won't work. If you really need database storage of geo data you might want to look at ckanext-mapstore:
https://github.com/geosolutions-it/ckanext-mapstore